# How to solve this semi gaussian definite complex integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gaussian-integral

How can I solve this definite complex integral :

$L=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-{\lambda r^2}-jr \zeta_1+j\zeta_2}dr$
where :
$\lambda , \zeta_1, \zeta_2$ are real and constant values and $\,j =\sqrt{-1} \,$.

Comment: Complete square in r.

Comment: I didnt understand @dustin

Comment: @Electricman Is $\lambda > 0$?

Comment: yes it is. @kobe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to complete the square in the $r$. That is, write 
$$
-\lambda r^2 - ir\zeta_1 + i\zeta_2 = -\lambda\Bigl(r+\frac{i\zeta_1}{2\lambda}\Bigr)^2+i\zeta_2-\frac{\zeta_1^2}{4\lambda}
$$
We can now write your integral as
$$
\exp\Bigl[i\zeta_2-\frac{\zeta_1^2}{4\lambda}\Bigr]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\biggl[-\lambda\Bigl(r+\frac{i\zeta_1}{2\lambda}\Bigr)^2\biggr]dr
$$
Let $u = r+\frac{i\zeta_1}{2\lambda}$. Then $dr = du$ so we have
$$
\exp\Bigl[i\zeta_2-\frac{\zeta_1^2}{4\lambda}\Bigr]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda u^2}du
$$
For $\lambda > 0$, the integral is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$. Note the following integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}\tag{1}
$$
The goal with integrals like yours is to manipulate into the form of equation $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer @dustin

Answer (score 0):

We use the noation $j=i$.
 
Use that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2+bx+c}dx=\sqrt{\pi\over a}e^{{b^2\over 4a}+c}$ 
 to get the answer $\sqrt{\pi\over \lambda}e^{{-{\xi_1}^2\over 4\lambda}+i\xi_2}$

Comment: please see my last edit on the equation. The $\lambda $ is changed to $-\lambda$ . Is the answer still same? @srinivas-k

Comment: I think this is the correct answer now. They missed a - behind $\zeta_1$ @srinivas-k

Comment: I just plugged the terms into the formula. The other answers are actually better bcoz' they show the entire process.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer @SrinivasK

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$L = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda r^2 - jr\zeta_1}e^{j\zeta_2}\,dr = e^{j\zeta_2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda\left(r + \frac{j\zeta}{2\lambda}\right)^2+\lambda\left(\frac{j\zeta_1}{2\lambda}\right)^2}\, dr = e^{j\zeta_2}e^{-\frac{\zeta_1^2}{4\lambda}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\lambda\left(r - \frac{j\zeta_1}{2\lambda}\right)^2}\, dr.$$

By contour shifting, the integral on the right is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda r^2}\, dr$. To justify this, consider the contour integral

$$\int_{\Gamma(R)} e^{-\lambda z^2}\, dz$$

where $\Gamma(R)$ is a rectangle parallel to the axes, with counterclockwise orientation, and with vertices at $-R$, $R$, $-R + j\zeta_1/(2\lambda)$, and $R + j\zeta_1/(2\lambda)$,. The integrals along the vertical edges are $O(e^{-\lambda R^2})$, which is negligible as $R \to \infty$. Further, since $e^{-\lambda z^2}$ is entire, $\int_{\Gamma(R)} e^{-\lambda z^2}\, dz = 0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem. Hence, the contour shifting is valid and

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda\left(r - \frac{j\zeta_1}{2\lambda}\right)^2}\, dr = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda r^2}\, dr = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}.$$ So

$$L = e^{j\zeta_2 - \frac{\zeta_1^2}{4\lambda}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}.$$

Comment: why you all have different answer. However, I think your answer is correct and their are wrong. Bx I test and compare it with the derivation of a paper and I can get the final answer by your solution @kobe

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you. Are you saying $L=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$ @dustin?

Comment: @Electricman he meant $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda r^2}\, dr = \sqrt{\pi/\lambda}$.

Comment: I think you missed a - behind $\zeta_1^2$ @kobe

Comment: and you, @dustin , right?

Comment: @Electricman I added some justification for the contour shifting I mentioned. I hope it makes things clearer now.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. The way you explained is a bit more difficult than Dustin, I should study contour shifting  @kobe